# If humanity develops and uses hydrogen fusion and then abandons Earth, would we leave behind large, stable deposits of helium byproduct?

Tags: technology, science-fiction, far-future

I’m thinking of making airships and zeppelins very commonly used (for cool factor) in my pseudo-mid-20th-century novel, which takes place on Earth in the very far future, tens of thousands of years after most of modern humanity has abandoned the planet. Many of the circumstances that allow this setting to exist can be handwaved for now, but among other things, I want to explain where this new humanity gets all their helium, especially since we’re already running out of natural helium in the present. Is hydrogen fusion byproduct a plausible source of helium for a humanity living among these technological ruins? Would there be a reason for the helium to be stored in the first place, and could it last several millennia?

Comment: We are not running out of natural helium. Helium is a by-product of natural gas extraction; and it is *cheap*. Annual helium production is over 150,000,000 cubic meters, and could easily be higher if needed. The largest helium producers are the U.S.A., Algeria and Quatar. What happened was that between the world wars, the U.S. accumulated a Very Large stockpile of helium, which they thought would be a strategic material for use in airships. The age of airships never came, and after WW2 the USA started selling off their massive stockpile, crashing the price. *That stockpile* is what ran out.

Comment: Ohh, that’s where all the “running out” talk is coming from. Guess I must be doing too much research on Facebook . For now, it seems I can keep all of my airship scenes in the book unchanged.

Comment: @AlexP: Helium is a byproduct of natural gas production, but in a world that has practical fusion power, and is aware of the dangers of fossil fuel extraction, there would be little or no natural gas production.

Comment: @jamesqf: So they would mine for helium. It is like any material which is not in great demand -- it is produced as a by-product of mining for something more useful. Think cobalt; nobody was mining for cobalt until about a decade ago, and the little cobalt which was needed was obtained as a by-product of the extraction of other metals. Then cobalt became interesting in its own right, and now mining companies are developing cobalt mines. (Plus of course they would still have petrochemistry, wouldn't they? Yes, it's only a small fraction of the extracted hydrocarbons, but it is still massive.)

Comment: @AlexP Helium is used far and wide, including in packaging perishable food (to prevent oxidation and remove requirements for certain bacteria to thrive), cooling applications (the low molecular weight and unique properties of Helium make it near ideal for super-cooling), and other industrial processes. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noble_gas#Applications

Comment: @GOATNine: Yes, it is used, otherwise its value would be zero and nobody would produce helium. The point is that the demand can easily be satisfied by what helium is produced *without looking specifically for helium.* That's what a **by**-product means; if it was completely useless it would be a **waste** product not a by-product. (Or more likely left as a harmless impurity in the natural gas.) (Currently there are helium extraction facilities which are sitting idle, because the demand is lower than the production capacity.)

Comment: helium deposits? currently our only helium 'deposits' come from radioactive element decay, not some cosmic ray shooting helium into the crust.

Comment: @AlexP Where are you getting facts to put your assertions above Tuskiomi's, for one?

Comment: @Whey_Isolate Would it be safe to reduce the Question to "Does hydrogen fusion produce large, stable deposits of helium…"?

Comment: @AlexP: But if the future civilization mines natural gas deposits just for helium, then they are faced with the cost of disposing of the waste (natural gas) from that mining.  Of course a future civilization that has progressed to practical fusion tech would presumably have also developed chemistry & biology to a point where "petrochemistry" has become unnecessary, and indeed uneconomic, since any organic compounds can be produced more cheaply in other ways.

Comment: @GOATNine I highly doubt they're using helium in food packaging as that would be a tremendous waste. Inert gas in food packaging is most likely nitrogen, but could also plausibly be argon in special cases. Argon is more easily available than helium, and nitrogen is extremely abundant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There wouldn’t be enough helium produced. Fusion of hydrogen to helium releases about 0.645% of the mass as energy — let’s call it 1% for a back-of-the envelope calculation. Global energy consumption is around 100,000 TWh — let’s say that cheap fusion would increase that, and call it a million TWh. That’s 3.6E21J. Dividing by the square of the speed of light (9E16), that’s a mass of 40 tons converted to energy per year, which would produce 4,000 tons of helium per year.

Filling one *Hindenburg*-sized airship once needs about 20 tons. So even if a thousand years’ worth of fusion by-product was still lying around (it wouldn’t be), you could fill 200,000 airships and then you’d run out. That’s quite a large number, but nowhere near enough to sustain global commercial aviation for the long term.

Comment: For comparison, Quatar alone produces about 50,000,000 cubic meters of helium per year, which is about 9,000 tonnes.

Answer (score 8):

No, it wouldn't last for millennia.

First of all, helium has very small molecules and it leaks from any container holding it. It is actually used to leak test vacuum connections, because it goes easily through any opening.

Therefore no container can reasonably store helium for millennia.

And, to complete the picture, Earth's gravity is not enough to hold helium with the current temperatures. All the helium would escape Earth's gravity well and go into outer space, as it happens with any helium we vent today.

Comment: They probably could store it in depleted natural gas geologic reservoirs.

Comment: @ksousa: Would that work? I know that Hydrogen leaks _through metal_, which is why the connections to fuel up rockets' tanks are there until the last moment, keeping pumping to compensate for the leaks. Helium being the next element on the list, I wouldn't be surprised to learn it also goes through metal, and anything really. It's _much_ lighter/finer than natural gas.

Comment: Burying it in depleted natural gas reservoirs puts it under at least half a mile of dirt and rock. You don't think that would protect it better than a few inches of metal?

Comment: Natural gas deposits are sometimes discovered by detecting the leaking gas (generally methane). How long a pure helium will last is a matter of luck - and yes, it can be millenia. That's how helium-rich natural gas deposits form in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Helium is in fact a renewable resource.

The radioactive atoms (uranium and thorium) underground slowly decay by emitting alpha particles (helium nuclei) and the helium slowly seeps out. It is very good at seeping out.

When a combination of conditions is met, a (relatively) gas-tight dome forms underground and gases (helium, methane and friends) build up in the rocks under the dome.

And there is a catch: we don't know all the mechanisms of methane formation underground so we don't know if it does replenish itself, but we pretty much know about helium - it is a radioactive decay product. You wait - and your depleted helium rich natural gas deposit has pressure again and is even more helium rich, because the helium producing isotopes are long-lived (they half-decay in bilions of years).

On the other hand, it looks unlikely that the future nuclear-fusion using people will even try to store waste helium underground. First, it is environmentally absolutely safe and second, the reactors will probably not produce much of it anyway (you get a great deal of energy by producing a miniscule amounts of helium). This is why underground storage efforts like those proposed for CO2 are unlikely.

Comment: There are no renewable atoms. Radioactive atoms decay, helium escapes to space, and that's it. The radioactive atoms don't undecay and redecay and emit more helium.

Comment: Depending on the scale, there is no renewable anything. The Sun will die in few billion years. Helium is renewable at the timescale discussed - the helium deposits are constantly replenished by U/Th decay and also constantly (not really depending on human activities) dissipated to the atmosphere and to space. Uranium and Thorium have very long half-lifes and don't get measurably less for a few thousand years. That's why the He production can be considered of constant rate.

Answer (score 2):

[Humanity currently produces 140 million cubic meters of Helium](https://www.statista.com/statistics/925214/helium-production-worldwide-by-country/).  Each cubic meter is about 180 grams, so that comes to 25k tonnes per year.

Using the Kardashev scale, I'll assume a K1 civilization powered by fusion on the Earth.  This civilization has to either build massive radiators, or dump heat in the planet core, to avoid boiling the surface.  Going much beyond K1 is going to require even more exotic solutions.

A K1 civilization in that sense has 2*10^17 Watts of power, which is 6 * 10^24 J/year.

D-T fusion to produce He is 0.645% efficient.  So for every J of energy produce, 1/0.00645 J = 155 J of He is produced.

This means 6 * 10^24 J of energy produces 9 * 10^26 J of Helium.  Divide by c^2 to get mass gives us 10^10 kg, or 10^7 Tonnes (10 million tonnes) of Helium produced per year.

Earth's atmosphere is 10^18 kg.  If a civilization that lasted 100,000 years produced that much Helium per year, that would be 10^15 kg of Helium.

The current atmosphere is 5 ppm, 3 * 10^23 helium atoms leak out of it per second.  I'll assume this rate varies linearly with Helium concentration in the atmosphere.

Earth's atmosphere is about 10^44 molecules.  At 5 ppm, there are 5*10^38 Helium atoms in the atmosphere, of which about 6 in 10^16 leak out per year.  If you mass produced Helium (like above), you'd lose only a tiny fraction of it over a non-geological time period, at least until your Helium changed the thermodynamics of the Earth's atmosphere.

So, a 100,000 year long fusion powered K1 civilization that had massive heat pumps that dumped heat in the Earth's core would leave the Earth's atmosphere with about 0.1% Helium by mass, and that amount would last over relatively long periods of time; I think the sun would swallow the Earth first.

At 0.1% Helium, I could imagine it being economical to harvest it.  Going a step further, one could imagine the buried fusion reactors still running, and venting Helium to the surface in certain areas.

Now, such a technology level is quite ridiculous.

Comment: A K1 civ wouldn't be bound exclusively to earth. and if it were, it'd cook the planet.

Comment: @ths You can either dump the heat into the planet's core (bury your fusion reactors) and/or build ridiculous radiators (and I mean ridiculous).  Also, you could build a sun shade.  It isn't trivial, but like I said, "such a technology level is quite ridiculous".

Answer (score 1):

Helium has many applications. If it were cheaper it would be quickly used in other ways, it is unlikely that it would be left to the future generations. Even if some technological advances reduced helium uses in some fields the use would increase in other fields. For example lets imagine that a new superconducting material allows to build powerful magnets at the temperature of liquid nitrogen, that would cut the annual demand for helium by a third, at that point it could become so cheap that the use of helium as inert atmosphere in many industrial processes would quickly grow and swallow the extra production.